# CiviCase + CiviRules + Tokens

Tags: civicase, tokens, civirules

I would like to trigger an email to a particular Role on a Case (not the Client) when a Case Status is changed. Is this possible? I've added the CiviCase Tokens Extension, and I can create a message template to be triggered (containing CiviCase tokens, such as the name of the client), but CiviRules doesn't appear to have the option to specify a different email on the Case.

I tried to use the token {case_roles.*role*_email} in the 'Use alternative email' option in CiviRules, but it doesn't see that as a valid email address.

Any other ideas I can try?

Comment: "to trigger an email to a particular Role on a Case" pedantic moment - do you mean "to trigger an email to any Contact that has a particular Role on a Case"? Also which CMS?

Comment: Sort of - there will only ever be one contact with the role I'm interested in, so it's synonymous. The Contact on the Case with this Role. 
Drupal.

Comment: check Drupal Rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CiviRules. The trigger is then Case is changed. At the condition you can select Field Value Comparison to check for the right case status.

At the action you select: Send E-mail to contacts on a case'

It might be that you need two condition with the field value comparison, one of the old case status and one for the new case status.

You need for this the CiviRules extension and the Email api extension.

Comment: @jaap-jansma-civicoop thanks for this. I have both extensions (and both updated) but I don't have an option to 'send e-mail to contacts on a case'. I only have 'send e-mail' and (twice) 'send e-mail to a related contact'. 

Also, I'm not sure if this is a separate issue, but I wanted to include a link to the {$manageCaseURL} - using the CiviCase Tokens extension - but this didn't load at all. It just returned the text as-is (i.e. "{$manageCaseURL}" ) not the result. Would you expect this to work?

Comment: Are you using a case trigger? E.g. case activity added, case added etc?
If so then the action send e-mail to a role on the case becomes available. 
Not sure about the CiviCase Tokens Extension ideally it should work but it wouldn't suprise me if it doesn't.

Comment: I'm using the 'Case is changed' trigger. The only option including the word 'role' is 'set role on case'? CiviCRM v5.21.2 and CiviRules v2.13. Seems a bit odd?!

Comment: Do you have the e-mail api extension installed?

Answer (score 0):

On the change case status activity, there's a section called send a copy where you can select them. Or put the person in the assignee field. Both will cause them to be sent an email.

Comment: I want to send a specific email template, rather than a copy of a CiviCRM activity. It's for an external person, so the assignee option isn't appropriate. Your answer makes me think it's not possible, and it will always need to be a manually generated email?

Comment: The message template it uses is the one called "Cases - send copy", so if you're willing to edit that template it can have whatever you want.